# ¿Existe algún proverbio similar a "The wish is father to the thought" en español?

Tags: traducción, proverbios

"The wish is father to the thought" es una referencia shakesperiana. Se refiere a que rápidamente creemos, o nos convencemos, de aquello que deseamos.

He estado intentando buscar alguna expresión idiomática que corresponda a esta frase, pero no lo he conseguido. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Interesante. El opuesto es _No hay peor ciego que el que no quiere ver_, también con la misma idea

Comment: Parecido a "wishful thinking", ¿no?

Comment: Sí, tendría el mismo significado.

Answer (score 1):

Por empezar, quizás sea importante destacar que la frase de Shakespeare

> ***The wish is father to the thought***

replica una idea expresada ya varios siglos atrás por el mundo griego

> *Ya que lo que desea cada hombre es lo primero que cree.*
>
> Demóstenes (384 AC-322 AC,  Político ateniense)

o, en la casi textual cita de Plotino (205-270, Filósofo griego)

> ***El deseo engendra el pensamiento***
>
> [image: frase de Plotino]

El sentido general de esa idea la expresa muy bien el propio idioma inglés, que tiene en su uso corriente una frase muy usada respecto a los riesgos del auto-engaño, de hacerse ilusiones y creerse las propias fantasías

> **wishful thinking**

En castellano para referir a eso —conocido técnicamente como una forma de [sesgo cognitivo (de confirmación) por la vía del **pensamiento ilusorio**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesgo_de_confirmaci%C3%B3n)— se suele decir

> ***formular una expresión de deseos***
>
> ***creerse(se)*** [alguien] ***las propias fantasías***
>
> o
>
> ***construir castillos en el aire***

A propósito del refranero español —como el depósito de sabiduría popular destilado por siglos— he dado con dos ejemplos de ese concepto, dentro del "Diccionario de Refranes (recopilados por el Presbítero José María Sbarbi y publicado en Madrid en 1922)

[image: Refranes, Adagios, Proverbios]

Ellos son:

> ***Quien bueyes ha perdido, cencerros se le antojan.***
>
> o, su variación
>
> ***Quien bueyes ha perdido, los cencerros trae al oído.***
>
> [para decir que la persona que está obsesionada con una idea en todas partes y a cada momento cree hallar algo que se la recuerda]

junto a estas

> ***Quien tiene hambre, de pan habla, o trata.***
>
> ***Quien hambre tiene, con pan sueña.***
>
> [por cuanto la fijación con el deseo de algo hace que en todas partes se crea verlo representado]

Comment: Agrego, que muy coloquialmente (en Argentina), la manera en que se señala el hecho de que alguien hable proyectando su deseo es comentando o acotándo con sorpresa (burlona) `¡las ganas!`, o `¡...ya quisíera !`

Answer (score 0):

"Querer es poder" es similar aunque no exactamente basado en el sentimiento (deseo) sino en la actitud (perseverancia). Al ser basado en una frase de Shakespeare es probable que demore en aparecer en otros idiomas.

Quizás más cercano es "La necesidad es la madre de la invención". Si se interpreta "thought" en general, como un pensamiento nuevo y no una convicción o ideal. "Necesidad" es un poco más básico que "Deseo" pero al menos se relaciona.

O este refrán (aparentemente de Confucio): "Hacer verdaderos los pensamientos significa no engañarse a sí mismo"

Comment: Sí,es un poco diferente porque la primera tiene una connotación negativa, de convencerse de algo que no es real. La segunda es positiva,similar a: Persevera y triunfarás

Comment: Aunque es negativa cuando la convicción es por algo real e imposible, también puede ser positiva, ya que uno persevera para conseguir algo que no existe aún y no es real.

Answer (score 0):

> **Shakespeare entre nosotros: Frases que utilizas todos los días y que no sabías que son de Shakespeare.**
>
> No cabe duda que el tesoro literario que hederamos de Shakespeare es incalculable y que ha sido comentado durante siglos, pero para celebrar su 400 aniversario luctuso en Veritas quisimos recordar esas frases y conceptos que enriquecen nuestro lengua y pensamiento que son herencia directa del gran escritor inglés.
>
> [...]
>
>  El deseo es el padre del pensamiento.
>
>  *Wish is father to that thought* (2 Henry IV)

Obtenido de:
https://www.veritasmedios.org/cultura-y-entretenimiento/shakespeare400anos-frases-que-utilizas-todos-los-dias-y-que-no-sabias-que-son-de-shakespeare.html